# Передать значение по ссылке с помощью POST

Tags: ajax, php, yii

В yii есть неведомый мне `CHtml::ajaxLink()`,
но он вроде как работает с текущей страницей,
а мне бы хотелось передать постом данные на другую страницу.

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
$text = 'Click me', 
$url = 'https://toster.ru/question/new', 
$ajaxOptions=array (
    'type'=>'POST',
    'dataType'=>'json',
    'success'=>'function(html){ jQuery("#des1roer=true").html(html); }'
    ), 
$htmlOptions=array ()
);
```

То бишь указать ссылку (https://toster.ru/question/new), имя поста (des1roer) и значение (true)
и на конечной странице отобразить:

```
if (isset($_POST['des1roer'] ))
   echo $_POST['des1roer'] ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да для кроссдомена есть несколько вариантов.

1. Обращаться к себе на сервер, а уже на нем тянуть с помощью `curl`
2. [jsonp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)
3. Доступ также будет, если на втором сервере для ответа присутствуют несколько заголовков:
   `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`
   `header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');`
   `header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, content-type');`
   звездочка в первом заголовке указывает, что отдавать можно всем, можно перечислить конкретно.

Answer (score 0):

То, что вы пытаетесь сделать, называется "Кроссдоменный AJAX". Обычный AJAX хорошо работает внутри домена приложения, вызывающего этот самый запрос, но когда нужно выполнить запрос на другой домен - возникают сложности.

Подробнее об этом можно почитать в статье на Хабре ["Кроссдоменный AJAX"](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114432/).

Там же есть ссылка на библиотеку [easyXDM](https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM).

В вашем случае `CHtml::ajaxLink()` вряд ли справится.

Comment: Но по кнопке же все красиво. Помню, реализовывал как-то нативно в связке php+js. Может, есть способ съэмулировать работу кнопки, а выводить как ссылку?

Comment: Для easyXDM не важно, чем она вызывается, кликом по ссылке или иным событием. Если не особо мучится, то можно сделать php proxy. Суть в следующем: по клику на ссылку отправляется AJAX запрос на специальный URL вашего сайта, контроллер выполняет cURL к внешнему ресурсу, получает ответ и возвращает клиенту. Но тут есть проблема: все запросы пойдут с IP вашего сервера и если на внешнем ресурсе есть ограничение количества запросов с одного IP, скрипт не всегда сможет получить ответ и правильно отработать

Answer (score 0):

Если не охота работать с cURL так же можете использовать старый добрый file_get_contents() и обрабатывать данные, а AJAX запросом забирать их.